# ML solution of a large Dirichlet PDF using optimx()

Tags: r

I have tried gradient ascent to find ML solution to an 18 category Dirichlet model in R using the optimx package, but I can find initial parameter values that will make the CG algorithm run. I have tried different combinations of positive integers for the alphas. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Code:

```
####Dirichlet log likelihood function
LnL_Dir <- function(alpha, p, N){
expr1 <- log(gamma(sum(alpha)))
expr2 <- sum(log(gamma(alpha)))
expr3 <- alpha-1
expr4 <- log(p)
lnl <- N*(expr1 - expr2 + sum(expr3*expr4))
return(-lnl)
} 

###gradient function
grad_Dir <- function(alpha, p, N){
expr5 <- digamma(sum(alpha))
expr6 <- digamma(alpha)
expr7 <- log(p)
gradient <- N*(expr5 - expr6 + expr7)
return(-gradient)
}

inits <- rep(c(1),18)    

optimx(inits, LnL_Dir, grad_Dir, method=c("CG"), p=theta.x, N=300)
```

The error message that is returned is:
"Cannot evaluate function at initial parameters"